# How can I make an HTML colour rectangle look better?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show a coloured rectangle in a table and make it look nice, but I'm terrible at HTML / CSS.

This is what I have (and it looks like garbage):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      #2E21FF&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="background-color: #2E21FF;border-width=1px;border-style:solid;border-color:rgb(204,204,204);padding:0;margin:0;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This minicolor demo has a nice swatch in the input, but I can't seem to even come close to it:

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Kieveli/9hjm9Lkf/

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Just so you're aware - you know they're using Bootstrap as a framework, yes?

Comment: Yes - I have bootstrap with css included in my project, but trying to copy / paste their span, it doesn't show up. So I've taken to reproducing their effect via manual classes.

Comment: Can't you simply use their library?

Comment: I do use their library to edit the colour, but in another view, I show a list of objects and associated colours.  In this table I'm trying to show a colour swatch.  This list is non-editable.

Comment: How about adding a border radius and a border like they do? `border: solid 1px #fff;
border-radius: 3px;`

Comment: OO! I think that's part of the ticket!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `td` is styled differently with a class `color-box` and all the colors are then separately handled with their classes, giving you re-usability of code and simple implementation.

```css
.color-box span {
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.color-box {
  border: 1px #aaa solid;
  padding: 6px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 0 #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 0 #888;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 0 #888;
}
.blue-box {
  background-color: #0088cc;
}
.red-box {
  background-color: #ff6161;
}
.green-box {
  background-color: #70c24a;
}
.yellow-box {
  background-color: #e0e03e;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="color-box">
      <span class="blue-box"></span> #0088cc
    </td>
    <td class="color-box">
      <span class="yellow-box"></span> #e0e03e
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color-box">
      <span class="green-box"></span> #70c24a
    </td>
    <td class="color-box">
      <span class="red-box"></span> #ff6161
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this give you a start?

https://jsfiddle.net/9hjm9Lkf/1/

```
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 5px 6px 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: calibri;
  color: #777;
}

td span {
  background-color: #716bc7;
  border-left=1px solid #ccc;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Top shelf! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can find many examples in this page : [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/working-with-shapes-in-web-design/)

Here, an example with a square and a triangle :

```css
.square {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #0074d9;
  border-radius: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.triangle {
    margin-left: 4.5cm;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-left: 100px solid #0074d9;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<h2>Just some shapes : </h2>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: Cool link! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example how to create a coloured rectangle in a table.

```
 td {
              border:solid thick darkblue; border-radius: 1em; 
              border-width:3px; padding-left:9px; padding-top:6px; 
              padding-bottom:6px; margin:2px; width:980px;
    }


    <table>
      <tr>
        <td 

    <span "background":#ff0000;    
             width:200px;
             height:100px;
             display: inline-block></span>;
    </td>
      </tr>
```